# Не могу понять логику работы счетчика

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть задача:

> Определите среднее значение всех элементов последовательности, завершающейся числом 0. Использовать массивы в данной задаче нельзя.

Я её сделал, вот код моего решения:

```
number = int(input())
amount = 0
sumSequence = number

while number != 0:
    number = int(input())
    amount += 1
    sumSequence += number

print(amount, sumSequence)
mean = sumSequence / amount
print(mean)
```

Были проверены все тесты - программа работает правильно, но я не могу понять, почему она работает, т.к. по моей логике в ней должна быть ошибка.

Поясняю, в коде есть переменная `amount`, подсчитывающая количество элементов последовательности, которая изначально равна 0. Увеличиваться эта переменная должна с началом работы цикла.

Наример, пользователь вводит последовательность `1, 7, 9, 0`. Программа считывает 1 вне цикла, поэтому `amount`  продолжает быть равным 0. Затем, когда начинает работу цикл, `amount` с каждым вводом увеличивается до тех пор, пока пользователь не введет 0. Пользователь вводит 7 - amount равняется 1, вводит 9 - равняется 2.

Почему тогда в итоге, после работы цикла, `amount` равен 3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это работает потому, что вы увеличиваете счётчик `amount` и в том случае, когда `number == 0`.Выход из цикла происходит на следующей итерации уже после увеличения счётчика.

Если добавить вывод отладочной информации на печать - становится понятнее, что происходит в цикле:

```
while number != 0:
    number = int(input())
    amount += 1
    sumSequence += number
    print(f"number:\t{number}\tamount:\t{amount}\tsumSequence:\t{sumSequence}")
```

ввод: `1, 7, 9, 0`, вывод:

```
number: 7       amount: 1       sumSequence:    8
number: 9       amount: 2       sumSequence:    17
number: 0       amount: 3       sumSequence:    17
```

---

Но лучше сделать код более понятным:

```
sum_ = 0
count_ = 0

while True:
    num = int(input())
    if num == 0:
        break
    sum_ += num
    count_ += 1


res = sum_ / count_
```